# Changing background cell of table depending on value

Tags: css

My site reads a XML file that contains information (values) for a data-table.
I use CSS to style the table and everything works fine.

To get a better user-experience I wondered if it is possible to change the background color of each cell dynamically depending on its value?

For example:

Each cell that contains a number less then "5" has a red background color;

each cell >= "5" has a green background color.

My first solution on this is to use Javascript - but I want to know if there is a way to solve this with CSS-styles only?

Comment: You could probably do this with CSS only using [attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp). You'd just need one for every single value between the min value and max value. That'd be an extremely large amount of CSS. It's not practical, but it IS possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't possible with *just* CSS (though you can use JavaScript to assign classes to enable it to be partially implemented with CSS). To use plain JavaScript, rather than a library:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
    if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) > 5){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    else if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) < -5){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VW7D6/).

Or, to use CSS classes:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableID');
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
    if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) > 5){
        cells[i].className = 'red';
    }
    else if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) < -5){
        cells[i].className = 'green';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VW7D6/1/).

References:

- [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className).
- [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style).

Comment: deleting my comment, thanks for clarifying i wish i read the code through better; upvoting for that

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: Is this still the case or has there been some new feature added to css since 2011 that supports this?

Answer (score 7):

Not to sure about css.I'll jump straight to jquery

```
$('#mytable tr td').each(function(){
  if($(this).text() > 5)$(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

without loop
you can do it this way

var val="ff";

$("#grid td:contains('"+val+"')").css('background-color', 'red');

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to do this using CSS expressions, but this is non-standard and IIRC only works in Internet Explorer. So I'd advise against it.

Doing this server-side or using JavaScript are your best bets.

Answer (score -1):

To add css to one particular column values only then thisn't going to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).