# Need to compare cell values then change background depending on result

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller, css-tables

EDIT: The only answers I've found use tables, not divs, so they don't really help me. I am not using an actual table, I'm emulating a table with divs.

I'm styling divs to appear as a table, and I need to be able to compare 2 cells in a row and then change the background color of the row if the `budget` cell value is smaller than the `actual` cell value. I'm pretty new to MVC, and web design in general.

Here is my code that creates the table with data I pull in from a database:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="cell">Client Name</div>
        <div class="cell">Project Name</div>
        <div class="cell">Budget</div>
        <div class="cell">Budget Used</div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var client in Model)
    {
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">@client.Client_name</div>
        <div class="cell">@client.Project_name</div>
        <div class="cell">@client.Project_budget</div>
        <div class="cell">@client.Project_actual</div>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

And here is where I style the table in my css:

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.header {
    display:table-header-group;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.rowGroup {
    display:table-row-group;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:27%;
    color:#696969;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    border-left:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    border-right:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    border-top:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
}
```

Comment: CSS can't detect content...only style it. How are you proposing to do this comparison?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing background cell of table depending on value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666500/changing-background-cell-of-table-depending-on-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using a variable for the class name of each cell, and changing the variable based on the values.

```
@foreach (var client in Model)
        {
            double calcPercent = ((@client.Project_actual / @client.Project_budget) * 100);
            string percent = String.Format("{0:0.00}", calcPercent);
            string cell = "cell";
            if (calcPercent > 100) { cell = "redCell"; }
            <div class="row">
                <div class="@cell">@client.Client_name</div>
                <div class="@cell">@client.Project_name</div>
                <div class="@cell">@client.Project_budget</div>
                <div class="@cell">@client.Project_actual</div>
                <div class="@cell">@percent</div>
            </div>
        }
```

CSS:

```
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:27%;
    color:#696969;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    border-left:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    border-right:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    border-top:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    background-color:#CEF6F5;
}
.redCell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:27%;
    color:#696969;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    border-left:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    border-right:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    border-top:solid 1px #5ec5ca;
    background-color:red;
}
```