# Coloring Line in Table in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

Is it possible to color a line in a table view in the Dashboard based on the content of the table?

For example: In a list of Salesmen highlight in red all salesman with more than $200,000 of sales in the last month.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is something you can currently do off-the-shelf - but this is something you could probably hack together by adding some custom js and css:

- Create your own override.js and override.css to implement something similar to what's described in [Changing background cell of table depending on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666500/changing-background-cell-of-table-depending-on-value)
- Add your css and js files to `/superset/templates/superset/basic.html`
- Rebuild / restart your superset server (see https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#making-your-own-build)