# javascript programming with jinja values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a block of HTML code

```
<td>{{stock.C4}}</td>
<td>{{stock.C5}}</td>
<td>{{stock.C6}}</td>
<td>{{stock.C7}}</td>
<td>{{stock.C8}}</td>
```

{{stock.C4}} has an output of None in the html cell.
I want (maybe javascript?) code that basically says

```
 if {{stock.C4}} == 'None'
       element.style.backgroundColor = "red"
```

code that makes the cell a color based on the html/jinja value

Comment: You at least need brackets around the if condition

Comment: [Loop through all the `td`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065342/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-javascript) and check the `innerHTML` of each item. If that matches to 'None', then change its background.

Comment: How does one check the innerHTML of {{stock.C4}}?

Comment: Seems to be duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666500/changing-background-cell-of-table-depending-on-value

Comment: You might try something like this (assuming that you are using [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)) : `{{#stocks}}{{#isNone}}<td style="background:red">{{/isNone}}{{^isNone}}<td>{{/isNone}}{{C4}}</td>{{/stocks}}`. Of course, the`isNone` predicate is not provided, you have to implement it by yourself following the instructions given at Github.

Comment: @bimlas question is similar, maybe a corner case, but the solution may be different

Answer (score 2):

If the content of the cell il really empty, you can add the rule

```
td:empty {
    background-color: red;
}
```

to your css (adapt the selector and the styles to your needs).

the [:empty pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) is supported since ie9 (no need to say that other browser support it from day zero).
Also mobile support seems quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the `td` of a specific table, the use `array#forEach` to check if it is empty using `innerHTML`, if so use `classList.add` to add a css class to it

```js
var getAllTD = document.querySelectorAll("#demoTable td");
getAllTD.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.innerHTML === '') {
    item.classList.add('empty')
  }


})
```

```css
.empty {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="demoTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 29,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: It seems you are trying to apply forEach on a non array

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) (that requires to change your data structure) :

```js
var stocks = [
  ["A1", "A2", "None"],
  ["None", "B2", "B3"],
  ["C1", "None", "C3"]
];

var view = {
  stocks: stocks,
  isNone: function () {
    return this == "None";
  }
};

var template = ""
+ "{{#stocks}}"
+   "<tr>"
+     "{{#.}}"
+       "{{#isNone}}<td class=\"none\">{{.}}</td>{{/isNone}}"
+       "{{^isNone}}<td>{{.}}</td>{{/isNone}}"
+     "{{/.}}"
+   "</tr>"
+ "{{/stocks}}"
;

var table = document.getElementById("table");
table.innerHTML = Mustache.render(template, view);
```

```css
table,td{border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;}
td.none{background:#ffa7b7}
td{padding:.25em}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```